# dict: unpacking some value and collect the rest like JS?

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

In Javascript, we can do `const {a, b, ...rest} = {a: 10, b: 20, c: 30, d: 40};`, and `rest` will be `{c: 30, d: 40}`.

Is there any way to do this in Python?

I can use `itemgetter` to achieve like

```py
dic = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30, 'd': 40}
a, b = itemgetter('a', 'b')(dic)
```

How can we collect the rest key-val pairs to `rest`?

=======

This is the best I could work out:

```
>>> dic = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30, 'd': 40}
>>> a, b = [dic.pop(i) for i in ['a', 'b']]
>>> a
10
>>> b
20
>>> dic
{'c': 30, 'd': 40}
```

Comment: Hello, can you please describe how does the desired output should look like?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to keep the original dict, then your solution already work. Just in case if you want to put them into the same line:

```
dic = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30, 'd': 40}
a, b, rest = [dic.pop(i) for i in ("a", "b")] + [dic]
print(a, b, rest)
```

Output:

```
10 20 {'c': 30, 'd': 40}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is subtracting 2 dictionary by using `all` and `pop`.

```
dic = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30, 'd': 40}
ab = {'a': dic.get('a'), 'b': dic.get('b')}
rest = dic
all(map(rest.pop, ab))   # function all() works for Python 2 and 3.

print(ab)
print(rest)
```

The result will be

```
{'a': 10, 'b': 20}
{'c': 30, 'd': 40}
```